# Install Ubuntu can't see my second hard drive

Tags: installation, windows-7, hard-drive

When installing Ubuntu 13.04 Desktop, It doesn't show my second hard drive as an installation option. I am trying to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7 on another hard drive. Windows 7 sees my second drive fine, and it is also listed in the bios. Another strange thing is that Install Ubuntu sees my first drive( the one I have Windows 7 on ) fine, but is says "No operating system detected". Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to UNPLUG your Windows HDD and only leave your blank HDD plugged in then start the Ubuntu Live CD, I have seen Ubuntu not detect two HDD's before. That should solve any confusion. Then use your BIOS to choose between HDD's to boot.

Comment: By any chance, are the two HDD's connected to the motherboard using separate ribbon cables or are they piggybacked to one? A lot of times certain systems won't detect the second piggybacked HDD.

Comment: No, they are separate.

Comment: By the way, I am using a live USB, not a CD, in case that helps.

Comment: Also, the drive I am trying to install Ubuntu on is older, and is IDE. The other drive( with windows 7 ) is SATA.

Comment: Alright.. If you to unplug the Windows SATA HDD, then does Ununtu see your IDE HDD?

Comment: No, it just shows no hard drive. Could it have something to do with it not being a master drive? I tried messing around in the bios with my IDE adapter. No luck.

Comment: That's what I was getting at.. Try changing your Secondary hard drive to your Primary and see if it works.

Comment: I will try, but I need to get a hopper( right? ). And right now I don't have one.